# Original Object Affected by reduce change in clone variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, dojo, javascript-objects

I have a code below, every time after its get reduce its referring my same array, how to resolve this

`var myobjData = data[0];`

```
var obj = myobjData;
var arr = ['index', 'label', '__id', 'id', '__parent', '__proto__'];

var colObjLength = shorten(arr, obj);

function shorten(arr, obj) {
  arr.forEach(function(key) {
    delete obj[key];
  });
  console.log(obj);
  return obj;
}
```

the `data[0]` gets affecting because of this code. it should not affect the `data[0]` value

Comment: what is `myobjData`?

Comment: You need to deep copy `data[0]` into `myObjData` instead of just assigning the reference.

Comment: it is a variable , i used it to store my data[0] value

Comment: how to do that deep copy data[0]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/122704#122704

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: use the `dojo/_base/lang` [.clone()](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#clone) method

Answer (score 0):

Use the use the `dojo/_base/lang` [.clone()](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#clone) method in oroder to create a clone of the obj, then do what ever you want to this last , so the original object will'nt be affected ,

**NOTE :** it's usless to delete key **proto** because it define the prototype of your object see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/proto)

Below a working snippet

```js
require(["dojo/_base/lang"], function(lang) {

  var arr = ['index', 'label', '__id', 'id', '__parent', '__proto__'];

  var obj = new Object();
  obj.index = "index";
  obj.label = "label";
  obj.__id = "1";
  obj.id = "id";
  obj.__parent = "__parent";
  
  //perform clone 
  var colObjLength = lang.clone(obj);

  colObjLength = shorten(arr,colObjLength);
  
  console.log("Original object",obj);
  console.log("Cloned object",colObjLength);




  function shorten(arr, obj) {
    arr.forEach(function(key) {
      delete obj[key];
    });
    return obj;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```